# SSRS 2008 & Column Headers

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

As you may be aware there is a peculiar situation with the display of column headers in SSRS2008... i.e. you need to dig around a bit to get them to repeat on every page.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx

All of the examples I've seen rely on some kind of grouping going on. I'm not using groups in my report. Any idea how I can get the headers of a tablix to appear on each new page.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest including a dummy field in the dataset, set to a constant value throughout the report. Group at the top level on the dummy field, move the tablix column headings into the group header and follow the rest of the steps in the MSDN blog.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Advance Group]

select Advance Mode in Group Properties

Select Static Group from Row Group

in Static Group Properties, 
set RepeatOnNewPage as True
and additionally KeepWithGroup as After

by setting this, 
you can view row header in each and every pages.

thanks.